# Ansible how to select hosts based on certain attributes and use their ip addresses to create a list at runtime

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-filter

I have a specific question about data manipulation in ansible.

In my inventory file, I have a group called postgresql as below:

```
[postgresql]
host1 ansible_host=1.1.1.1 postgresql_cluster_port=5432 postgresql_harole=master
host2 ansible_host=2.2.2.2 postgresql_cluster_port=5432 postgresql_harole=slave postgresql_master_ip=1.1.1.1
host3 ansible_host=3.3.3.3 postgresql_cluster_port=5432 postgresql_harole=slave postgresql_master_ip=1.1.1.1
host4 ansible_host=4.4.4.4 postgresql_cluster_port=5432 postgresql_harole=slave postgresql_master_ip=1.1.1.1
```

Somewhere in my playbook I will need to manipulate and use filters to make a list of ip addresses of all hosts whose postgresql_harole=slave as below:

```
- hosts: postgresql
  gather_facts: True
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - set_facts:
        slave_ip_list: "{{ expressions }}"
```

I am pulling my hairs to have the correct expressions... any help is highly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Q: ***"List of ip addresses of all hosts whose `postgresql_harole=slave`"***

A: Select the attribute from *hostvars*, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        slave_ip_list: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                           selectattr('value.postgresql_harole', 'eq', 'slave')|
                           map(attribute='value.ansible_host')|
                           list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  slave_ip_list:
  - 2.2.2.2
  - 3.3.3.3
  - 4.4.4.4
```

---

Select the *hostvars* for the group *postgresql* first if there are *hostvars* for other hosts, e.g. as a result of `- hosts: all`. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        slave_ip_list: "{{ groups.postgresql|
                           map('extract', hostvars)|
                           selectattr('postgresql_harole', 'eq', 'slave')|
                           map(attribute='ansible_host')|
                           list }}"
      run_once: true
```

---

**Update**

You can simplify both the code and inventory. Put the declarations into the *group_vars*. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/postgresql
postgresql_cluster_port: 5432
postgresql_master_ip: "{{ groups.postgresql|
                          map('extract', hostvars)|
                          selectattr('postgresql_harole', 'eq', 'master')|
                          map(attribute='ansible_host')|first }}"
postgresql_slave_ip: "{{ groups.postgresql|
                         map('extract', hostvars)|
                         selectattr('postgresql_harole', 'eq', 'slave')|
                         map(attribute='ansible_host')|list }}"
```

Then, you can remove *postgresql_master_ip* and *postgresql_cluster_port* from the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[postgresql]
host1 ansible_host=1.1.1.1 postgresql_harole=master
host2 ansible_host=2.2.2.2 postgresql_harole=slave
host3 ansible_host=3.3.3.3 postgresql_harole=slave
host4 ansible_host=4.4.4.4 postgresql_harole=slave
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: postgresql
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          ansible_host: {{ ansible_host }}
          postgresql_harole: {{ postgresql_harole }}
          postgresql_master_ip: {{ postgresql_master_ip }}
          postgresql_cluster_port: {{ postgresql_cluster_port }}
          postgresql_slave_ip: {{ postgresql_slave_ip }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [postgresql] ****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_host: 1.1.1.1
    postgresql_harole: master
    postgresql_master_ip: 1.1.1.1
    postgresql_cluster_port: 5432
    postgresql_slave_ip: ['2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_host: 2.2.2.2
    postgresql_harole: slave
    postgresql_master_ip: 1.1.1.1
    postgresql_cluster_port: 5432
    postgresql_slave_ip: ['2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']
ok: [host4] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_host: 4.4.4.4
    postgresql_harole: slave
    postgresql_master_ip: 1.1.1.1
    postgresql_cluster_port: 5432
    postgresql_slave_ip: ['2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_host: 3.3.3.3
    postgresql_harole: slave
    postgresql_master_ip: 1.1.1.1
    postgresql_cluster_port: 5432
    postgresql_slave_ip: ['2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host4: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: thanks @Vladimir Botka, this is very helpful!

Comment: and I did some adaptation as below, but still the same idea.

` "{{ groups['postgresql'] | map('extract', hostvars) |selectattr('postgresql_harole', 'eq', 'slave')|map(attribute='ansible_host')|list }}" `

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is probably to use Ansible's `group_by` module, which allows you to create groups dynamically based on the values of host variables.  For example, given this inventory:

```
[postgresql]
host1 ansible_host=1.1.1.1 postgresql_cluster_port=5432 postgresql_harole=master
host2 ansible_host=2.2.2.2 postgresql_cluster_port=5432 postgresql_harole=worker postgresql_master_ip=1.1.1.1
host3 ansible_host=3.3.3.3 postgresql_cluster_port=5432 postgresql_harole=worker postgresql_master_ip=1.1.1.1
host4 ansible_host=4.4.4.4 postgresql_cluster_port=5432 postgresql_harole=worker postgresql_master_ip=1.1.1.1
```

We can group hosts using the `postgresql_harole` variable like this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: create group of postgresql workers
      group_by:
        key: "pg_role_{{ postgresql_harole|default('none') }}"

- hosts: pg_role_worker
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - run_once: true
      debug:
        var: groups.pg_role_worker

    - debug:
        msg: "Hello world"
```

Running the above playbook would generate output similar to:

```
PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [create group of postgresql workers] ****************************************************
changed: [host1]
changed: [host2]
changed: [host3]
changed: [host4]

PLAY [pg_role_worker] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host2] => {
    "groups.pg_role_worker": [
        "host2",
        "host3",
        "host4"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "Hello world"
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": "Hello world"
}
ok: [host4] => {
    "msg": "Hello world"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host4                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You can see that (a) there now exists a group `pg_role_worker` containing hosts `host2`, `host3`, and `host4` and that (b) the final `debug` task runs only on those hosts.