# Include host group to other group based on boolean variable

Tags: ansible

How to include a host group into another host group depending on a host boolean variable?

```ini
[group-1]
hostA a=true
hostB b=true
hostC a=true b=true c=true

[group-a]
# I expect here hostA and hostC due to a=true
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [*constructed inventory*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/constructed_inventory.html) along your normal inventory for this use case.

As pointed in [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/constructed_inventory.html), a constructed inventory allows you to

> uses Jinja2 to construct vars and groups based on existing inventory

So with the inventories

- *inventory.ini*

  ```ini
  [group_1]
  hostA a=true
  hostB b=true
  hostC a=true b=true c=true
  ```
- and *inventory.constructed.yml*

  ```yaml
  plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed

  groups:
    group_a: a
    group_b: b
    group_c: c
  ```

We can then run any Asnible command specifying those two:

```bash
ansible-inventory --graph \
  --inventory inventory.ini \
  --inventory inventory.constructed.yml
```

Which will yield

```
@all:
  |--@ungrouped:
  |--@group_1:
  |  |--hostA
  |  |--hostB
  |  |--hostC
  |--@group_a:
  |  |--hostA
  |  |--hostC
  |--@group_b:
  |  |--hostB
  |  |--hostC
  |--@group_c:
  |  |--hostC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build host inventory in task:

```yaml
- add_host:
    groups: group-a
    hostname: '{{ item[0] }}'
  when: item.a == True
  with_items: "{{ groups['group-1'] }}"
```

Another solution would be group hosts with same values, in this case `a=true` by ansible module `group_by`:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Group hosts by variable 'a'
      group_by:
        key: "new_hosts_group_{{ a|default() }}"
- hosts: new_hosts_group_true
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - run_once: true
      debug:
        var: groups.new_hosts_group_true
    - debug:
        msg: "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: is it possible to not write any host? What I expected is like a filter which allowes me to just add hosts with flags and don't change any other code.

Comment: @javadev check updated answer or this [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67029581/ansible-how-to-select-hosts-based-on-certain-attributes-and-use-their-ip-address)